# Jira Portfolio - Progress bar shows no progress

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I have a portfolio set up for my Project in Jira.  It contains 6 or 8 epics and there are varying numbers of Jira tasks associated to each epic.

The Portoflio Scope view shows the epics and the tasks under each epic but the progress bar displayed for each epic or it's linked tasks does not show progress, even for epics where 90% of the tasks are marked resolved or closed.

All tasks have Original Estimates, Remaining time and those that are resolved, fixed have time logged against them.

I cannot find anything useful int the [Jira Docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiraportfoliocloud/tracking-progress-and-status-828785247.html) for tracking progress.  I presume this is down to some smal config option or some feature of the epics or tasks but I cannot for the life of me work out what it might be.

We are using the cloud version of Jira.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so we found the reason behind my issue.  By default the portfolio Scope view was showing epics for my project with the 2 releases I was interested in.  There is a **More** option on this filter and under that was **Completion date**.

By default this completion date seems to be **since the beginning of: Current Sprint**.  This meant that all tasks marked resolved or closed were excluded from the list of tasks under the epic on the portfolio board...hence, no progress.

I'm not sure why tasks listed as completed under the current, active sprint were not listed based on the default Completed filter though?  Maybe it is because the portfolio was set up based on a Project rather than a Sprint Board?

Anyway, changing the completion date to something else then meant the completed tasks were included under the epics and I am now seeing lots of green progress bars!